# Printing smallest values from a column from rows where values in a different column were larger using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like the following:

```
            prov_code     stdev    median  counts   average
15680  1518170208       NaN  0.003956     1.0  0.003956
9819   1326073214       NaN  0.005536     1.0  0.005536
12158  1396892758  0.002297  0.008135     5.0  0.007002
7294   1235493859       NaN  0.011872     1.0  0.011872
10241  1336302850       NaN  0.011971     1.0  0.011971
538    1013948579       NaN  0.012109     1.0  0.012109
12262  1407192602       NaN  0.014108     1.0  0.014108
1729   1053544775  0.003417  0.018708     3.0  0.018736
9987   1326336603  0.015904  0.024315     3.0  0.018938
5614   1184677494  0.001838  0.021293     4.0  0.020641
14932  1487910469  0.015710  0.022984     2.0  0.022984
2410   1073857090  0.006663  0.022355     4.0  0.023586
885    1023447968       NaN  0.023651     1.0  0.023651
```

I am printing this using:

```
print(df1.nsmallest(50,columns=['average']))
```

I would like to print the 50 smallest values for average when the counts are higher than a certain number say 100.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Replace `df1` by `df1[df1.counts > 100]`.

Comment: `df1.query("counts > 100").nsmallest(....)`